# I have For without Next Error, not sure why

Tags: excel, vba

Following code I'am getting data from multiple sheets into a master workbook.
When run the macro I have the error:  For without Next.

```
Sub copydata()

Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String

FolderPath = "C:\Users\stefan.georgescu\Desktop\Verificari\"

Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xlsx"

Filename = Dir(Filepath)

Dim erow As Long, lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

Do While Filename <> ""

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)

    Do
        For counter = 1 To 5

        Dim ws As Worksheet

        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

        Do
            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

                wb.Worksheets(counter).Activate
                lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
                'Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
                Workbooks("VerificariCEgeneral.xlsm").Worksheets(counter).Activate
                erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                Cells(erow, 1).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            Next
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(erow, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to declare *counter* variable.

Comment: Indenting your code will do wonders to prevent those kinds of errors. See my edit to your question, makes the missing `Next` more obvious

Comment: You may also want to read  up on [avoiding activate and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I've got one word for you: indentation, indentation, indentation.

Comment: @SJR: technically speaking, that's 3 words :)

Comment: `Option Explicit` is your friend

Comment: You have no closure for the second and third do's.  Missing out the closure for a do loop gives a misleading missing next error message. i.e. I would expect to see three Loop statement, 1 to match each do.  That's why it called a do Loop.

Comment: @Zac - counting is not my strong point. If I were to use 3 different words I would add your two too.

Comment: In addition to using "option explicit" and properly indenting your code there's another small and easy trick you can apply: Name your "for..next" loops. If the index your "for..next" uses  is "ws", write "next ws" at the end of your loop instead of a plain "next". I will help you to keep track of those loops.

Comment: Hi All! Thank you all for your support! Sorry, but I am a novice at VBA. I tried to put for each Do (2'nd and 3'rd) > Next, but now I have error on line "End Sub: Do without Loop"